# Heroku Procfile for tomcat embedded

Tags: heroku, embedded

I have jsp java project with Tomcat embedded and for run I use two steps.

mvn clean install
mvn tomcat7:run

How can I configure my Procfile to run on heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to run your production web process from Maven. Instead, you'll need to choose between these two options:

- [Configure Tomcat Webapp-Runner in your `pom.xml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner)
- [Deploy a WAR file to Heroku and let it provide Tomcat](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment)